# Using VBA to loop through each column and sort from largest to smallest

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sorting

I have a dataset comprised of numbers in excel containing 300 rows and 2677 columns, I'm looking to loop through each of the columns and sort them from largest to smallest.

I tried to modify the code below but can't find a way to loop through each of the columns and sort by largest to smallest, can anyone help me please?

```
    Range("I5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("I5:I312" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Sort
        .SetRange Range("I5:I312")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code. No need to select anything, selection only consumes Excel resources, not bringing any benefit:

```
Sub SortColumns()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastCol As Long, i As Long
 Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet3")
 lastCol = 2677 'it can be calculated, if all existing columns should be sorted
 With Application 'a little optimization
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 End With
 For i = 1 To lastCol
    sh.Range(sh.cells(5, i), sh.cells(5, i).End(xlDown)).Sort key1:=sh.cells(5, i), _
                  order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, Orientation:=xlSortColumns
 Next i
 With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 End With
End Sub
```

The above code assumes that no empty cells exists in the sorted ranges. If they may exist, the last row of the range to be sorted should be calculated in a different way. I kept your way of calculating, but without selection...

Answer (score 1):

### Sort Columns Descending

- It is assumed that the data starts in cell `I5` on `Sheet3` of the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SortColumnsDescending()
' Needs the 'RefColumn' function.
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Sort Columns Descending"
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet3"
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "I5"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range(FirstCellAddress)
    Dim lCell As Range
    Set lCell = ws.Cells(fCell.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
    If lCell.Column < fCell.Column Then Exit Sub ' no data in header row range
    
    Dim hrrg As Range: Set hrrg = ws.Range(fCell, lCell) ' Header Row Range
    Dim frrg As Range: Set frrg = hrrg.Offset(1) ' Data First Row Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim crg As Range ' Current Column Range
    Dim frCell As Range ' Current First Row Cell
    
    For Each frCell In frrg.Cells
        Set crg = RefColumn(frCell)
        If Not crg Is Nothing Then
            crg.Sort Key1:=crg, Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
            Set crg = Nothing
        'Else ' no data in column range
        End If
    Next frCell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Columns sorted.", vbInformation, ProcTitle
    
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range from the first cell
'               of a range ('FirstCell') to the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the first cell's worksheet column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

End Function
```